# Can I take string from a user, and if its definition is in a dict, print the definition in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, input

I'm relatively new to python, and I'm struggling to implement a program that prompts the user for the name of a fruit (e.g. Apple) and then outputs that fruit's calories in one portion of that fruit (e.g. 130). I also want to ignore any input that isn’t a fruit.
[Click here for desired output image][1]

I've tried to solve this problem using a dictionary, to match a name to its corresponding format:

```
    fruit_dict = {
            'Fruit':'Apple', 'Calories':'130',
            'Fruit':'Avocado', 'Calories':'50',
            'Fruit':'Banana', 'Calories':'110',
            'Fruit':'Cantaloupe', 'Calories':'50',
            'Fruit':'Grapefruit', 'Calories':'60',
            'Fruit':'Grapes', 'Calories':'90',
            'Fruit':'Honeydrew Melon', 'Calories':'50',
            'Fruit':'Kiwifruit', 'Calories':'90',
            'Fruit':'Lemon', 'Calories':'15',
            'Fruit':'Lime', 'Calories':'20',
            'Fruit':'Nectarine', 'Calories':'60',
            'Fruit':'Orange', 'Calories':'80',
            'Fruit':'Peach', 'Calories':'60',
            'Fruit':'Pear', 'Calories':'100',
            'Fruit':'Pineapple', 'Calories':'50',
            'Fruit':'Plums', 'Calories':'70',
            'Fruit':'Strawberries', 'Calories':'50',
            'Fruit':'Sweet Cherries', 'Calories':'100',
            'Fruit':'Tangerine', 'Calories':'50',
            'Fruit':'Watermelon', 'Calories':'80'

}
item = input('Item: ').strip().title()
if item in fruit_dict:
    print(fruit_dict.get)
```

Problem is, I don't know how to take a user output (e.g `Apple`) and print its definition (e.g `130`)

Appreciate you reading this long description. Anyone have ideas to implement such a program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionary is the correct approach but your implementation is incorrect, I have attached the correct code below, hope that helps

```
fruit_dict = {
    "Apple": "Calories: 130",
    "Avocado": "Calories: 50",
    "Banana": "Calories: 110",
    "Cantaloupe": "Calories: 50",
    "Grapefruit": "Calories: 60",
    "Grapes": "Calories: 90",
    "Honeydrew Melon": "Calories: 50",
    "Kiwifruit": "Calories: 90",
    "Lemon": "Calories: 15",
    "Lime": "Calories: 20",
    "Nectarine": "Calories: 60",
    "Orange": "Calories: 80",
    "Peach": "Calories: 60",
    "Pear": "Calories: 100",
    "Pineapple": "Calories: 50",
    "Plums": "Calories: 70",
    "Strawberries": "Calories: 50",
    "Sweet Cherries": "Calories: 100",
    "Tangerine": "Calories: 50",
    "Watermelon": "Calories: 80",
}
item = input("Item: ")
print(fruit_dict.setdefault(item, "Not a fruit"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Keys in dict are unique. So if you declare the dict as

```py
fruit_dict = {
    'Fruit':'Apple', 'Calories':'130',
    'Fruit':'Avocado', 'Calories':'50',
    'Fruit':'Sweet Cherries', 'Calories':'100',
    'Fruit':'Tangerine', 'Calories':'50',
    'Fruit':'Watermelon', 'Calories':'80'
}
```

the actual `fruit_dict` will be `{'Fruit': 'Watermelon', 'Calories': '80'}`

You can use the fruit name as the key, and the calories as the value.

The dictionary can be declared as

```py
fruit_calories_dict = {
    "Apple": 130,
    "Avocado": 50,
    "Banana": 110,
    "Cantaloupe": 50,
    "Grapefruit": 60,
    "Grapes": 90,
    "Honeydrew Melon": 50,
    "Kiwifruit": 90,
    "Lemon": 15,
    "Lime": 20,
    "Nectarine": 60,
    "Orange": 80,
    "Peach": 60,
    "Pear": 100,
    "Pineapple": 50,
    "Plums": 70,
    "Strawberries": 50,
    "Sweet Cherries": 100,
    "Tangerine": 50,
    "Watermelon": 80,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

lower casing all dictionary keys to simplify logic

```
fruit_dict = {
    "apple": "calories: 130",
    "avocado": "calories: 50",
    "banana": "calories: 110",
    "cantaloupe": "calories: 50",
    "grapefruit": "calories: 60",
    "grapes": "calories: 90",
    "honeydrew melon": "calories: 50",
    "kiwifruit": "calories: 90",
    "lemon": "calories: 15",
    "lime": "calories: 20",
    "nectarine": "calories: 60",
    "orange": "calories: 80",
    "peach": "calories: 60",
    "pear": "calories: 100",
    "pineapple": "calories: 50",
    "plums": "calories: 70",
    "strawberries": "calories: 50",
    "sweet cherries": "calories: 100",
    "tangerine": "calories: 50",
    "watermelon": "calories: 80",
}
fruit=input('Enter fruit name: ')
if fruit.lower().strip() in fruit_dict.keys():
    print(fruit_dict[fruit])
```

Output:

```
Enter fruit name: banana
calories: 110
```

hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

For a beginner, your idea of using a dictionary is a good sign of your understanding of the problem. However, the implementation is incorrect because you don't have a good grasp of what a python dictionary is.

You want to, given a string, output a value related to that string, am I right?

In a python dictionary, you can map non unique values with a unique key, like so:

`myDict = { key: value }`

which makes the value accessible by calling `myDict[key]`. In your case, the keys are not unique (Fruit & Calories).

So, your keys would be the names of your fruits, and the values associated with them are the calories.

```
fruit_dict = {
    "Apple": 130,
    "Avocado": 50,
    "Banana": 110,
    ...
}
```

Assuming the user correctly inputs the capitalized string, the value is now accessible by calling `fruit_dict[user_input]`.

To only take into account the fruits that are included in your dictionary, you need to check if the input is included in the list of keys of the dictionary using `list(fruit_dict.keys())`.

```
if user_input in list(fruit_dict.keys()):
  # do something here
```

Good luck!